# Heater Blower Disassembly

Tags: jeep, motors, heater-blower, wrangler

So i was attempting to fix my heater blower but, this is a very odd and panful thing to take apart
Anyone know how? i need to get to the rotor to clean it out and get to the stator

[image: Blower Motor]

Comment: In most cases, I don't think these are serviceable.

Comment: Often these are pressed or riveted together.  Remember that these are mass-produced units and are very cost sensitive.  So even saving a few $0.01 on each adds up.  A common cause of failure in many motors is an open-circuit in one of the windings.  That is very difficult to repair since you will lack the tools to re-wind it after replacing the wire.  You may be better off just getting a replacement.  A junkyard should yield you a salvage one if you're on a budget.

Comment: @jwh20 I have the equipment, and if powered directly by the brushes it spins (found out after posting this) I just need to get to the terminal wire behind the casing